# Eclipse IDE: Line (or mark) between code block start and end like in Notepad ++

Tags: eclipse, ide, block

I'm looking for a way to make eclipse shows a dot-line (or any kind of line) between code block begining and block end like in Notepad++.

See sample image:

http://s14.postimage.org/itrtkupg1/lines.jpg

Does anobody know how can Ido that in Eclipse?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in Eclipse... [bug 84878](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84878) has been opened way back in 2005, and has never been fixed.

Comment: The closest thing to this you can get is by enabling code folding and hovering mouse over "block collapse" marker.